# css max-height inside max-height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a chat page but I got a problem with the sizing of the divs :/
I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="chat-holder">
    <div class="chat-text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the page class is (let's say the width and the height of the screen so it is

```
.page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The chat-holder I want to have a width of 740px and the height should be any height but not more than the browser height and a background white and a 20px padding around the chat area (so far I tried this):

```
.chat-holder {
  background: #fff;
  width: 740px;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now my chat area I want to have a 1px black border inside this chat-holder and if the chat is not bigger than the browser minus that 40px padding, I want it to have the size of the text that is in it. If it is bigger, I want it to have scroll inside it (so far I tried this)

```
.chat-text {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

But this doesn't work, the chat-text div goes out of the chat-holder, as i see it is because the max-height doesn't work inside a max-height. I hope there is a work-around on this issue because I really don't want to use jQuery or something to fix it.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KjX7s/2/

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: How about using `overflow:auto` on your chat holder a la http://jsfiddle.net/KjX7s/6/. EDIT: Oops, forgot to put it in.

Comment: Instead of putting the `overflow:auto` on the `chat-text`, could you put the `overflow:auto` on the `chat-holder`?

Comment: it works if i use it on the .chat-holder but the layout is like that and i cant argue about it :) now in the meantime i was thinking to use an outline to make that line around the chat-text but i have another problem, the chat-text has a border-radius and look ho it looks on the edges :/ http://jsfiddle.net/KjX7s/8/

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the height as well as the max-height:

```
.page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.chat-holder {
  background: #fff;
  width: 740px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.chat-text {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KjX7s/14/

Comment: if i do this, when i have less content, it iwll not resize as it should http://jsfiddle.net/KjX7s/9/ it always shows it to max height

Comment: I thought that was exactly what you wanted =) Try to set a min-height then. I edited the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: i saw looking at your fiddle but the chat-holder does not keep that 20px paddin g around the chat-text, it just had max height :D i am using that chat-holder just to have like a border around the chat-text :)

Comment: Last try :) I hope it helps. The important is that you get the idea.

Comment: now we go back to square one :D when i add more content, it doesnt stop on the bottom of the page but goes off page :(

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
  overflow: auto;
```

inside `.chat-holder` .

And put an height calculated with CSS Calc():

```
max-height: calc(100% - 41px);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KjX7s/5/